# Нужна ли запятая и кавычки?

Tags: запятая

Но в принципе понятие вечные ссылки предполагает...

Ув. филологи! Очень интересует, нужно ли выделять запятыми "в принципе" в этом случае? Если да, то отделять ли "но" запятой:

Но, в принципе, понятие «вечные» ссылки предполагает...

Также интересует расстановка кавычек. Мой вариант:

Но в принципе понятие "вечные" ссылки" предполагает...

То есть беру в кавычки само понятие из двух слов и слово "вечные", так как реально они не являются вечными. Кавычки накладываются. Это верно? спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что лучше остановиться на таком варианте: "Но в принципе, понятие "вечные ссылки" предполагает..."

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Выражение "вечные ссылки" обычно используется в специальной литературе, поэтому его можно считать термином. Выделение кавычками в этом случае не требуется, например:
   "Вечные ссылки или автопродвижение? Сегодня методики поискового продвижения условно можно разделить на два вида: вечные ссылки и автопродвижение с помощью ссылочных агрегаторов".
2. Однако в приведенном примере ставятся кавычки, так как перед термином стоит приложение "понятие", которое относится к словосочетанию "вечные ссылки".
3. Слово "в принципе" является вводным словом со значением "по сути говоря", то есть используется для оформления речи. (Следует отличать от обстоятельства, например: "для меня это неприемлемо в принципе").
4. Присоединительный союз НО лучше объединить с вводным словом, в противном случае мы получаем дополнительно выделение вводного слова, а здесь это не нужно.

Comment: Решение спорных вопросов, связанных с постановкой запятых, желательно проверить с помощью интонации. Размещение "но в принципе" в начале предложения подсказывает нам, что перед нами, скорее, вводное слово, так как такое расположение для вводных слов весьма характерно. В роли обстоятельства "в принципе" обычно встречается в середине предложения, при этом оно интонационно и по смыслу тесно связано с определяемым словом. Постановка запятой после "НО" также проверяется интонацией. Отделяя вводное слово от союза запятой, мы выделяем его логически, а это авторский выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Ох, сложный этот вопрос...

Возможны оба варианта. Зависит от вкладываемого автором смысла.

~1. Если оборот "в принципе" используется в значении "по сути говоря", то обособление нужно: *'но, в  сущности, понятие... предполагает"* 
Речь здесь может идти, например, о том, что некое понятие было названо, использовано, а теперь поясняется другими словами. Или, скажем, в значении "на самом деле".

*При этом, однако, причин для отнесения союза НО к самому обособляемому обороту (и, как следствие, исключению первой запятой - см. София) я здесь не вижу, Да и интонационно было бы, думаю, ошибочно. Хотя в других случаях такое действительно возможно.*

~2. Если же это член предложения со значением "принципиально", "главным образом", то запятые не нужны: *"но в принципе (принципиально) понятие... предполагает"*.
Тут речь может идти, например, о том, что в теории (в принципе) оно так, но  на практике это сложно или невозможно.

см. здесь:
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_105

Что конкретно у Вас, сказать без контекста сложно. На практике первый вариант встречается, конечно, чаще, но это опасно обобщать на все случаи.

Впрочем, боюсь, что автор и сам может не понимать, какой из этих случаев у него представлен, оба смысла по контексту его устраивают. Тогда тут трудно что-то посоветовать. Оставьте тогда так, как нравится.